New house intentionally built with retention pond
A house we are looking at buying has a decently sized retention pond in our backyard. It was ordered by the county. Is this a red flag? What problems could it cause and what could we do to make it less of a nuisance?

You'd be much better off checking with the county. They are the ones that ordered it. Also check with previous owners about any problem they had with it. The only way to really make it less of a nuisance  is to move away from it.

Retention ponds are common place in Florida.  I have had an investment property with a retention pond behind.  I had no problems.  I never heard of anyone living next to or around a retention pond having any issues.  Some of people even found them beneficial, as it keep neighbors farther away.

There are quite a few people who'd pay really good money for any sort of waterfront view...that said: is this retention pond entirely on your property, or on some sort of shared outlot your lot backs up to?

@ThreePhaseEel  So a good size(acres) beaver pond on the back 40(far from the house) will bring in the money?

@crip659 -- chuckles not quite that distant, but I personally wouldn't mind a decent size beaver pond on the back 40, either

Many states/municipalities/localities require stormwater management for new construction nowadays.  Sometimes it's in the form of an infiltration pit, sometimes it's a rain garden (bioretention), sometimes it's permeable pavement.  I highly doubt a single residential property has a retention pond in its back yard—that's more like a development-wide type of BMP.  What exactly do you have?  Can you share a site plan?
